# Implementing pairwise linear distance in Scala

Tags: algorithm, scala, dataframe, linear-regression

Assume I have the following DataFrame in Scala Spark, where year `year` value is a String categorical representation, but there is an order in the data.

```
+-----+
|years|
+-----+
|  0-1|
|  1-2|
|  2-5|
| 5-10|
+-----+
```

I would like to create a resulting pairwise matrix, representing the "distance" for each pair of values. Same values are given a score of `1`, values at the extreme end are given `0` for eg. "0-1" and "5-10". The remaining values are filled with a linear model.:

I would like the following expected results (In DataFrame or similar structure to query a pair)

```
x/y, 0-1,   1-2,  2-5,  5-10,
0-1,  1   , 0.33, 0.67, 0,
1-2,  0.33, 1 ,   0.33, 0.67,
2-5,  0.67, 0.33, 1 ,   0.33,
5-10, 0   , 0.67, 0.33, 1
```

In the end, for a given pair of `years` I would like to retrieve the `distance` values. I would like to avoid hard coding this solution, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Not quite clear what you want to calculate here... How did you get `d(1-2, 2-5) = 0`?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin thanks for pointing that out -- I made a mistake it should be 0.33

Comment: So, you care only about the order of the elements, the numerical values are completely ignored, correct?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin You are right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply map your labels to points `0 = 0/g, 1/g, 2/g, ... , g/g = 1`, where `g` is the number of gaps between two adjacent labels, that is, number of labels minus one:

```
def similarityMatrix[A](xs: List[A]): Map[A, Map[A, Double]] = {
  val numGaps = xs.size - 1
  val positions = xs.zip((0 to numGaps).map(i => i.toDouble / numGaps)).toMap
  def similarity(x: A, y: A) = 1.0 - math.abs(positions(x) - positions(y))
  xs.map(x => (x, xs.map(y => (y, similarity(x, y))).toMap)).toMap
}
```

Your example:

```
val ranges = List("0-1", "1-2", "2-5", "5-10")
val matrix = similarityMatrix(ranges)

for (x <- ranges) {
  for (y <- ranges) {
    printf("%4.2f ", matrix(x)(y))
  }
  println()
}
```

Gives the following nested map:

```
1.00 0.67 0.33 0.00 
0.67 1.00 0.67 0.33 
0.33 0.67 1.00 0.67 
0.00 0.33 0.67 1.00
```

Works for any dimension, of course:

```
1.00 0.94 0.88 0.81 0.75 0.69 0.63 0.56 0.50 0.44 0.38 0.31 0.25 0.19 0.13 0.06 0.00 
0.94 1.00 0.94 0.88 0.81 0.75 0.69 0.63 0.56 0.50 0.44 0.38 0.31 0.25 0.19 0.13 0.06 
0.88 0.94 1.00 0.94 0.88 0.81 0.75 0.69 0.63 0.56 0.50 0.44 0.38 0.31 0.25 0.19 0.13 
0.81 0.88 0.94 1.00 0.94 0.88 0.81 0.75 0.69 0.63 0.56 0.50 0.44 0.38 0.31 0.25 0.19 
0.75 0.81 0.88 0.94 1.00 0.94 0.88 0.81 0.75 0.69 0.63 0.56 0.50 0.44 0.38 0.31 0.25 
0.69 0.75 0.81 0.88 0.94 1.00 0.94 0.88 0.81 0.75 0.69 0.63 0.56 0.50 0.44 0.38 0.31 
0.63 0.69 0.75 0.81 0.88 0.94 1.00 0.94 0.88 0.81 0.75 0.69 0.63 0.56 0.50 0.44 0.38 
0.56 0.63 0.69 0.75 0.81 0.88 0.94 1.00 0.94 0.88 0.81 0.75 0.69 0.63 0.56 0.50 0.44 
0.50 0.56 0.63 0.69 0.75 0.81 0.88 0.94 1.00 0.94 0.88 0.81 0.75 0.69 0.63 0.56 0.50 
0.44 0.50 0.56 0.63 0.69 0.75 0.81 0.88 0.94 1.00 0.94 0.88 0.81 0.75 0.69 0.63 0.56 
0.38 0.44 0.50 0.56 0.63 0.69 0.75 0.81 0.88 0.94 1.00 0.94 0.88 0.81 0.75 0.69 0.63 
0.31 0.38 0.44 0.50 0.56 0.63 0.69 0.75 0.81 0.88 0.94 1.00 0.94 0.88 0.81 0.75 0.69 
0.25 0.31 0.38 0.44 0.50 0.56 0.63 0.69 0.75 0.81 0.88 0.94 1.00 0.94 0.88 0.81 0.75 
0.19 0.25 0.31 0.38 0.44 0.50 0.56 0.63 0.69 0.75 0.81 0.88 0.94 1.00 0.94 0.88 0.81 
0.13 0.19 0.25 0.31 0.38 0.44 0.50 0.56 0.63 0.69 0.75 0.81 0.88 0.94 1.00 0.94 0.88 
0.06 0.13 0.19 0.25 0.31 0.38 0.44 0.50 0.56 0.63 0.69 0.75 0.81 0.88 0.94 1.00 0.94 
0.00 0.06 0.13 0.19 0.25 0.31 0.38 0.44 0.50 0.56 0.63 0.69 0.75 0.81 0.88 0.94 1.00
```

Comment: Thanks for the elegant solution, I got too caught up with using DataFrames that I forget to use other data structures such as Map, etc.

Comment: @Ivan This whole matrix basically fits on my screen (modulo rounding errors), it's tiny, so there would be no point storing it in a distributed dataframe anyway.

Comment: You're right. Seems like an overkill for a simple task, thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Ivan on the other hand, if you really wanted to, then it would be a simple `zipWithIndex`, then `map`, then `crossProduct`, followed by another `map`. Shouldn't be too difficult either.

Comment: Retrieval from a Map should be much faster as compared to storing it in a distributed DataFrame, I do need to access this map quite frequently